# JWT Token Authentification (Publish from Boostnote to Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, jwt

I'm trying to configure the [JWT Token Authentification of Boostnote](https://github.com/BoostIO/Boostnote/pull/1575) in order **to publish directly my notes into Wordpress**.

I followed [these instructions](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/), but coming to the USAGE part I'm lost...
I have modified the *wp-config.php* file and I have the namespace and endpoints */wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token{/validate}*.

But **how can I get the token** to fill in Boostnote next ?
What am I suppose to do with this function ?

```
( function() {

var app = angular.module( 'jwtAuth', [] );

app.controller( 'MainController', function( $scope, $http ) {

var apiHost = 'http://yourdomain.com/wp-json';

$http.post( apiHost + '/jwt-auth/v1/token', {
    username: 'admin',
    password: 'password'
  } )

  .then( function( response ) {
    console.log( response.data )
  } )

  .catch( function( error ) {
    console.error( 'Error', error.data[0] );
  } );

} );

} )();
```

Thanks!